# Updating page content with Ajax while avoiding duplicate entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, put

I'm making an Ajax Put request that combines with a user submitting a form to update an existing page with a string consisting of their name, email, and a skill proficiency level. Is there a way to include a search and replace of that string in the page in cases where the user accidentally resubmits the same information to the same page or wants to update their skill level?

```
function makeJSON() {
 var users_name = document.getElementById("users_name").value;
 var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
 inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
 for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  input = inputs[i];
  if (input.value.length > 1) {
   var skillString = "<p> " + users_name + " - " + input.value + " - " + email + '</p>';
   var skillName = input.name;
   $.get('/rest/api/content?spaceKey=EXPERTISE&title=' + skillName + '&expand=space,body.storage,version,container', function (data, status) {
    var pageData = data.results[0];
    var existing_body = pageData.body.storage.value

    // Check if email already exists in skill page
    if (pageData.body.storage.value.search(email)) {
      ??????????
    } else {
         pageData.body.storage.value = pageData.body.storage.value + skillString;
    }

    pageData.version.number += 1;
    var page_id = pageData.id;
    pageData.body.storage.value = pageData.body.storage.value + skillString;

    $.ajax({
      type: "PUT",
      url: "/rest/api/content/" + page_id,
      data: JSON.stringify(pageData),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    });
   });
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you keep track of what was added in a variable rather than in the DOM. What I mean by that is keep an array of all the values that were added to the page and avoid `pageData.body.storage.value.search(email)`

Comment: It's a good idea but it's intended for there to be quite a number of pages and values. In the future maybe some type of db could get implemented.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are asking. You can retrieve the text in a particular using `element.textContent()`. And can replace the text inside a DOM element using `element.innerHTML = newValue`, where element is a DOM element. Does that help?

Comment: The page content is being accessed via a rest API . Are you saying that `element.textContent()` and `element.innerHTML = newValue` should get applied in the .get request?